# Join two DataFrames such that the entries of one are appended to the array of the other

Tags: java, apache-spark, join, apache-spark-sql

I have the following data frames:

```
 |-- k1: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: long (containsNull = true)
 |-- k2: string (nullable = true)
 |-- k3: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: long (containsNull = true)
```

and

```
 |-- k1: long (nullable = true)
 |-- k2: string (nullable = true)
 |-- k3: long (nullable = true)
```

Note that the column names and types are identical, except that `k1` and `k3` of the first data frame are arrays. I would like to join these two data frames on `k2` such that the entries of the second data frame are appended to the array in the first data frame. For example, if the data frames are

```
+---------+---+------------+
|    k1   |k2 |      k3    |
+---------+---+------------+
|[1, 2, 3]|foo|   [4, 5, 6]|
|[7, 8, 9]|bar|[10, 11, 12]|
+---------+---+------------+
```

and

```
+-----+---+------+
|k1   |k2 |k3    |
+-----+---+------+
|    4|foo|     7|
|   10|bar|    13|
+-----+---+------+
```

Then the result of the join should be

```
+---+-------------+----------------+
|key|    click    |      search    |
+---+-------------+----------------+
|foo|[1, 2, 3, 4] |   [4, 5, 6, 7] | 
|bar|[7, 8, 9, 10]|[10, 11, 12, 13]| 
+---+-------------+----------------+
```

My first approach was to do an inner join to get

```
+---+---------+------------+-----+------+
|key|    click|      search|click|search|
+---+---------+------------+-----+------+
|foo|[1, 2, 3]|   [4, 5, 6]|    3|     6|
|bar|[7, 8, 9]|[10, 11, 12]|    9|    12|
+---+---------+------------+-----+------+
```

then do a foreach over the resulting data frame to append the desired row entry to the array, then finally drop the latter two columns. But I wasn't able to get the typing to work for the foreach.

I'm using Java 8 with Spark 1.6.1. I'm new to Spark so any guidance will be much appreciated.

Comment: Can you share the actual code you used for the join?

Comment: @NoelWidmer `df1.join(df2, "k2")` where df1 is the first dataframe (with the arrays) and df2 is the second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't a solution in Java, but perhaps the following approach in Scala using `UDF` for appending columns can serve as a reference:

```
val df1 = Seq(
  (Seq(1, 2, 3), "foo", Seq(4, 5, 6)),
  (Seq(7, 8, 9), "bar", Seq(10, 11, 12))
).toDF("k1", "k2", "k3")

val df2 = Seq(
 (4, "foo", 7),
 (10, "bar", 13)
).toDF("k1", "k2", "k3")

def appendCol = udf(
  (a: Seq[Int], x: Int) => a :+ x
)

val df3 = df1.join( df2, Seq("k2") ).
  withColumn( "click", appendCol(df1("k1"), df2("k1")) ).
  withColumn( "search", appendCol(df1("k3"), df2("k3")) )

df3.select( col("k2").as("key"), col("click"), col("search") ).show
+---+-------------+----------------+
|key|        click|          search|
+---+-------------+----------------+
|foo| [1, 2, 3, 4]|    [4, 5, 6, 7]|
|bar|[7, 8, 9, 10]|[10, 11, 12, 13]|
+---+-------------+----------------+
```

Comment: He is trying to implement in java and same thing in java is really tricky :O .  check my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Using java it's bit tricky.

Assuming both dataframes are registered as t1, t2 tables then union both array using udf.

```
sql.udf().register("unionArray", (Seq<Long> arr1, Seq<Long> arr2) -> {
            List<Long> output =new ArrayList<Long>();
            //Convert Seq object to java list and add to output
            output.addAll(scala.collection.JavaConversions.asJavaList(arr1));
            output.addAll(scala.collection.JavaConversions.asJavaList(arr2));
            //Convert java list output scala Seq
            return Option.apply(scala.collection.JavaConverters.asScalaIterableConverter(output).asScala().toSeq());
        }, DataTypes.createArrayType(DataTypes.LongType));

        sql.sql("select t1.k2 as key,unionArray(t1.k1,t2.k1) as click, unionArray(t1.k3,t2.k3) as search from t1 join t2 on t1.k2 = t2.k2").show();
```

Hope this would help.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I'm new to Spark and had no idea that Java is much less natural than Scala for its use. I think I will be using Scala instead because it seems like a better tool for Spark. I would upvote but I can't because I don't have enough rep.

Comment: Happy to help. Mark it as answered :)